# JQuery Page Number Switcher Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Tabs HTML

```
<a class="page_prev page_current" href="javascript:;" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">
    <span>prev</span>
</a>
<a id="Gal_Btn_P1" href="javascript:;" class="page-numbers page_current" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">1</a>
<a id="Gal_Btn_P2" href="javascript:;" class="page-numbers" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">2</a>
<a id="Gal_Btn_P3" href="javascript:;" class="page-numbers" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">3</a>
<a class="page_next" href="javascript:;" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">
    <span>Next</span>
</a>
```

### JQuery Code

```
    var Gal_C_Page = 1;
    var Gal_M_Page = 3;

    $('.tf_pagination a').click(function(e) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('page_current')) {

            $('.page_current').removeClass('page_current');
            $('#Page_' + Gal_C_Page).hide();

            if ($(this).hasClass('page_prev')) {
                if (Gal_C_Page == '2') {
                    $(this).addClass('page_current');
                }
                Gal_N_Page =  Gal_C_Page - 1;
                $("#Page_" + Gal_N_Page).show();
                $('#Gal_Btn_P' + Gal_N_Page).addClass('page_current');
                Gal_C_Page = Gal_N_Page;
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('page-numbers')) {
                Gal_N_Page = $(this).text();
                $("#Page_" + Gal_N_Page).show();
                $(this).addClass('page_current');
                if (Gal_N_Page == Gal_M_Page) {
                    $('.page_next').addClass('page_current');
                } else if (Gal_N_Page == '1') {
                    $('.page_prev').addClass('page_current');
                }
                Gal_C_Page = Gal_N_Page;
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('page_next')) {
                if (Gal_C_Page == Gal_M_Page + 1) {
                    $(this).addClass('page_current');
                }
                Gal_N_Page = Gal_C_Page + 1;
                $("#Page_" + Gal_N_Page).show();
                $('#Gal_Btn_P' + Gal_N_Page).addClass('page_current');
                Gal_C_Page = Gal_N_Page;
            }
            alert(Gal_C_Page);
        }
    });
});
```

### The Problem

Well if my JQuery code does not look like a whole load of crap and over complicated, the only problem I am having is;

- Clicking through (1, 2, 3...) - Works
- Clicking Next Through - Works
- Clicking a number then next - Variable then becomes 11 or 21.

I've included a Javascript tag for this question as I'm not fussed on how it's done as long as I can get some help in resolving.

I've tried multiple edits whereas the code added here is my current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gal_N_Page = $(this).text();` Will give you a string, and string + number = string, e.g: `'1' + 1 = '11'`.
So change to `Gal_N_Page = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);`

Comment: Thank you very much, to see this working, just wow, I am so relieved right now! (P.S 9 minutes till I can award answer)